# Simple issue with Chr() and Output file

Tags: .net, vb.net, file, ascii, streamwriter

i'm on vb .net (2005 & 2010), and have an undesired output when writting ascii chars to a file.

On the debug console, i get (chr(128, chr(147), chr(130)):

```
€
“
‚
```

On the file, i get:

```
â‚¬
â€
â€š
```

It some kind of rubbish? y need to delete them, the line MUST start with € and the others.

I'm System.IO.StreamWriter and it's .WriteLine method, with and without flushing.

Thanks!

Comment: These are not ASCII, since ASCII is 7-bit, they'd have to be ordinal code 0 through 127, not 128 and above. What encoding are you writing that file in?

Comment: Pass Encoding.Default to the StreamWriter constructor.

Comment: I've to write a file and send it to a spooler, it reads this file and print an invoice. In the printer's manual, it says: (ASCII 128).

Comment: @HansPassant with Enconding.Default it prints an '?'. I'll try with the others type.

Comment: @HarzIce: Your printer's manual is broken then - ASCII doesn't *have* a value of 128...

Comment: Jeje, in any value it says (ASCII 130), (ASCII 147) and so.... I've a example file (that works), and it's written in the right way. I can't get the same output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `StreamWriter` uses UTF-8 as the encoding unless you specify anything else.

It's not at all clear what you're using to *read* the file - but if you can make it read the file as UTF-8, it may well show what you were expecting.

Personally I would avoid using `Chr`, favouring the more portable `ChrW` which doesn't rely on the current thread's settings for the default encoding.

Now, as to what the file *ought* to contain - it really depends on what's going to read it. I generally think UTF-8 is a *good* encoding to use, but it's clearly not the one you were expecting...

Comment: The print spooler will read this file, and print according the lines i wrote. If the line, ie number 2, does not begin with the euro symbol, the printer will cancel the operation.

Comment: @HarzIce: Well a file consists of *binary* data. Is the printer actually expecting a byte value of 128? If you're trying to write binary data, you shouldn't be using text.

Comment: It contains a special character at start, and then texto (such as descripcion and quantity of a product). But it saves 226 128 and not 128 alone.

Comment: @HarzIce: "Special character" is a phrase which fills me with fear. Basically it sounds like you want some *binary* data, then some text data. If you want the byte 128, then you should write that directly to a `FileStream`.

Comment: i.e. I need to write chrW(147) + chr(28) + "r" + chr(28) + "T".  The '28' works ok 'cause it ascii. i'm searching for a filestream example. thanks.

Comment: @HarzIce: If you've been given specific bytes to write, then *don't think of them as characters at all*. Even if the manual mentions ASCII, it's basically misinformed.

Comment: OK, Using filestream and binarywriter, it get what i need. Thank you. Thank you all.

Comment: @HarzIce: Excellent - glad to hear it. Now complain to the printer manufacturer about the poor documentation :)

Answer (score 0):

Its probably something to do with encoding. I had something similar happen when I checked a bat file into tfs. By checking the file in an encoding was set that put a special character in the first character of the file that caused and error when I ran the bat file.

I hope this helps...

Comment: Yep, something i'm missing. I'm trying with differents encoding now. no luck, yet. Thanks.